# boost ptree-how to modify XML using iterators?

Tags: c++, xml, boost

I am working on a XML file that looks like this:

```
<persons>
  <person>
    <name>NAME1</name>
    <ID>ID1</ID>
  </person>
  <person>
    <name>NAME2</name>
    <ID>ID2</ID>
  </person>
  <person>
    <name>NAME3</name>
    <ID>ID3</ID>
  </person>
... etc
</persons>
```

I need to replace all the names by "OTHERNAME".
When I use the code that folows, one of the name is replaced by OTHERNAME.

```
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>
using boost::property_tree::ptree;

ptree pt;
read_xml(filename,pt);
ptree &pt_persons = pt.get_child("persons");
ptree &pt_person = pt_person.get_child("person");
pt_person.put("NAME","OTHERNAME");
```

I, however, want to replace all the names so I tried this code:

```
ptree pt
read_xml(filename,pt);
ptree &pt_persons = pt.get_child("persons");
for( ptree::iterator &it = pt_persons.begin(); it != pt_persons.end();it++){
        ptree &pt_person = it->second;
        pt_person.put("NAME","OTHERNAME");
}
write_xml(filename, pt);
```

My problem is that this code doesn't do anything.
My guess is that the iterator is not a reference to the node I want to modify but to a copy of this node.

Do you have any suggestion?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which boost library are you using?

Comment: I think its Boost Property tree.

Comment: Post the real iterator code, the above is uncompilable.

Comment: Furthermore, `pt_personne` is probably a typo for `pt_person`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve my problem I decided to use TinyXML.
It is a lot easier to use for updating and modifying XML files.